# Cross-site loading of objects slowing/freezing page loads

Tags: bug, website

Apologies if this is in the wrong place, I've experienced the same thing across other stackexchange sites but I spend most time here so I'm posting in meta here.

Browser is FireFox 22.0, with Ghostery, Adblock plus running but nothing on this site blocked.

Basically, when I open questions in new tabs, FireFox will freeze up whilst trying to load content on the new tab - usually waiting on stuff from cdn.sstatic.net and mathjax.org

I realise there's as much chance this is FF's fault as anyone's, I'd just be happy for it to behave itself by whatever means.

Comment: I run FF 22.0, Adblock but unblocked here as well so all the same but no Ghostery and don't have any problems. I guess you could try disabling Ghostery but I think both those sites you've mentioned serve static content, maybe you have some local / ISP caching problem.

Answer (score 3):

If I had to place a bet on what's taking so long, it's MathJax, which is a (relatively) large download, and then it can slow down the loading of any page that renders MathJax. Compare a page with no MathJax to one with MathJax, and you should see a difference.